# TDE, OFDE and FDE equalizer simplest exmple in matlab

Tags: matlab, modulation, digital-communications, equalization, equalizer

I want to implement the equalizer in matlab. I am just learning this. I want a good kick start code that can help me to learn it further. I searched a lot on Google but do not find a good reference code to start. I have a received signal in matlab that is modulated with QAM-16 modulation and passed through AWGN Noise.

I do not know much about the equalizers, I also do not know how to find impulse response of that signal. can some body please help me to just let me start some piece of code so that I can learn more in this direction.

Thanks

Comment: A few points: 1) we don't normally just hand code over to people- the purpose of this forum is for you to do the work and come to us when you have questions, 2) equalizers are tricky because you need to produce the "error" signal somehow, and how you do that changes with the application, and 3) an equalizer will not help at all with AWGN.